# MUST I provide an NSSortDescriptor in core data when doing a fetch request?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data, macos

I wonder if I could just execute a NSFetchRequest with just the Entity and nothing else. However, it seems to work with no errors, but since I've never seen anyone doing that, I wonder if there are any bad drawbacks in doing this. The documentation doesn't say if there's any default value used instead when I provide no NSSortDescriptor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will work, but your objects will come back in an unpredictable order. If you really just need every instance of a single entity without regard to ordering, then yes, it will work the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `NSSortDescriptor` is optional as is the array of `NSPredicate` objects. As Alex says, you will get responses back in an unknown order, however you may wish to do this for a couple of reasons. You may wish to simply check whether you have at least 1 of a particular `NSManagedObject` or more typically if you are simply processing data (and not displaying it) then you simply need to enumerate across every object. In this case the order may not be relevant.